# Storing variable value before setting header

Tags: python, pandas

I have a unix LF csv file where the header is row 6. Rows 1-5 contain mostly unnecessary information except for 1 value. Is there a way to save a specific cell value (example, row 2, column 2) prior to setting the header? I'm trying to incorporate this using Pandas so I'm not sure if there's something I need to do within:

```
df - pd.read_csv(f, header = 6, lineterminator = "\n")
```

The goal is to create a column (Journal Entry) and use the same value for each row of the CSV. Multiple csv files will be combined so this will allow me to determine which journal entry is associated with the specific row. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can read the file twice,  once to extract information in rows 1-5 and second time to build core dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets pretend you have something like this:
[example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzpfL.png)

so your goal is to set the header with the number for your entry:

```
filename=(r'C:xxx\Book1.csv') #your path
df=pd.read_csv(filename, header=[1,5]) #my headers will be 1 and 5 (index)
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join) #and join the headers
```

output: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBVLb.png)

New to posting, but hope this helps